# One time change field + personal comments

Tags: entities, comments

I'm not very familiar with all the modules for Drupal. Therefore, let me try to explain what I'm looking for.

1) The users shall be able to create nodes with some specific fields. Some of those fields shall be writable only one-time.

2) To this node only the author and users allowed by the author shall have access.

3) Additionally the users who have access to nodes of another user shall be able to make comments (including attachments). Something like a discussion forum to each node, but only the author of the node and the creator of the comment shall see their nodes.

Hope it's somehow understandable.

Are there any kind of modules for any of the above requests?

Comment: Will the fields be created prior?

Comment: hm... what you mean by created prior?
There is a little client running that is posting nodes.
This client is giving using the MAC address for the prior created type of MAC_ADDR, but the fields are getting filled with values only during commit of the note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem. You can write hook_form_alter() in custom module and disable needed fields when user edit node. And configure permissions on this page admin/people/permissions

Comment: Got it!!!
Thanks! Will work on this. Seem the best solution.